# iOS: searching for cocoapods using the terminal

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, xcode8

Any of you know if is a way to make a search for cocoapods using the terminal. For example if I want to search for "CocoaLumberjack" ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a command to search for repositories. It's the following:

`pod search QUERY`

Where query is the name of the pod that you are looking for. It has several other options (flags). For more information, check the following link :

https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_search

Answer (score 1):

You just do:

`pod search CocoaLumberjack`

Answer (score 0):

There is! How might we find out?

`pod --help`

```
Usage:

    $ pod COMMAND

      CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.

Commands:

    ...
    + search        Search for pods
    ...
```

So we can run: `pod search cocoalumberjack`

```
-> CocoaLumberjack (3.0.0)
   A fast & simple, yet powerful & flexible logging framework for Mac and iOS.
   pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 3.0.0'
   - Homepage: https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack
   - Source:   https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.git
   - Versions: 3.0.0, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.0-rc, 2.1.0-beta, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0-rc2,
   2.0.0-rc, 2.0.0-beta4, 2.0.0-beta3, 2.0.0-beta2, 2.0.0-beta, 1.9.2, 1.9.1, 1.9.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.7.0, 1.6.5.1,
   1.6.5, 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0 [master repo]
   - Subspecs:
     - CocoaLumberjack/Default (3.0.0)
     - CocoaLumberjack/Core (3.0.0)
     - CocoaLumberjack/Extensions (3.0.0)
     - CocoaLumberjack/CLI (3.0.0)
     - CocoaLumberjack/Swift (3.0.0)

-> CocoaLumberjack-RemoteAccess (0.1.0)
   remote access log files on iPhone
   pod 'CocoaLumberjack-RemoteAccess', '~> 0.1.0'
   - Homepage: https://github.com/tomcat2088/CocoaLumberjack-RemoteAccess
   - Source:   https://github.com/tomcat2088/CocoaLumberjack-RemoteAccess.git
   - Versions: 0.1.0 [master repo]
...
```